# Can Istio Virtual Service Timeouts be limited to a particular request time

Tags: istio

It's possible to make Istio Virtual Service match only idempotent methods eg

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: "httpbin-virtual-service"
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - method:
        exact: GET
      uri:
        prefix: /status
      uri:
        prefix: /delay
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "httpbin"
        port:
          number: 80 # application port
```

BUT 
Is there a way to make Istio retries as Configured in the VirtualService apply only for idempotent requests eg GETS , while bypassing retries for non-idempotent requests eg POST (see below) . In terms of requirements, I'd like to retry only for methods that are not likely to change the state of the system if they are invoked multiple times? The `retryOn` would be an ideal place for this functionality, but I don't see how it could be used in it's current form (unless maybe with connect-failure/refused stream, if we assume that those errors indicate that the execution was never performed on the target service)

Thanks

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: "httpbin-virtual-service"
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
    - uri:
        prefix: /delay
    timeout: 15s
    retries: ============================> Is there a way to make the retries apply only for idempotent requests eg GETS
      attempts: 5      
      perTryTimeout: 1s
      retryOn: 5xx,gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "httpbin"
        port:
          number: 80
```

I tried this config , but a call to a POST (for instance), . .still seems to trigger the retries

eg

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: "httpbin-virtual-service"
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
      method:
        exact: GET
    - uri:
        prefix: /delay
    timeout: 15s
    retries:
      attempts: 5      
      perTryTimeout: 1s
      retryOn: 5xx,gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "httpbin"
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
      method:
        exact: POST
    - uri:
        prefix: /delay
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "httpbin"
        port:
          number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also in the same position as you not long ago.

Finally, I understood that the default behavior is 1 retry.

And if I wanted no retry, I had to override by setting 0 such as:

```
retries:
  attempts: 0
```

Please note that this seem to be supported only from 1.2.1 onwards: [Issue 14900](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14900)

Also quite interesting to watch out is this open [Issue 13851](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13851) (at least as of this writing). It seems POST is retrying even when the request was OK in the first try.

Please check and see if these help you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a config that works . See https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/17145